# What is the difference between function and Function in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am seeing a new Function parameter appear today.
[image]

Can some one tell what it is?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

A Javascript `function` is used to perform specific logical tasks in a block state. You can read more about this here on this [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Which in turn, as Tedinoz explained that "A `block` statement is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of braces ("curly brackets") and contains a list of zero or more statements and declarations".

See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Sample from the w3schools reference:

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  return p1 * p2;
}  
console.log(myFunction(2,3)); 
// should log 6;
```

for the `Function()` constructor creates function objects that can create functions dynamically. This can be understood further in this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function)

Sample from reference:

```
const sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum(2, 6));
// Expected output: 8
```

Comment: `Block`: "A block statement is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of braces ("curly brackets") and contains a list of zero or more statements and declarations". [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for the additional information, I'll include it in my answer and credit you properly for it.

Comment: @RajeebRoy If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)